# Optimizing the Huffman tree algorithm from O(n^2) to O(n) with priority queue C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, huffman-code

I've been given this code snippet for organizing a Huffman tree.

```
// Build a Huffman tree from a collection of frequencies
template <typename E> HuffTree<E>*
buildHuff(HuffTree<E>** TreeArray, int count) {
    heap<HuffTree<E>*,minTreeComp>* forest = 
        new heap<HuffTree<E>*, minTreeComp>(TreeArray, count, count); 
    HuffTree<char> *temp1, *temp2, *temp3 = NULL;
    while (forest->size() > 1) {
        temp1 = forest->removefirst();   // Pull first two trees  
        temp2 = forest->removefirst();   //   off the list
        temp3 = new HuffTree<E>(temp1, temp2);
        forest->insert(temp3);  // Put the new tree back on list
        delete temp1;        // Must delete the remnants
        delete temp2;        //   of the trees we created
    }
    return temp3;
}
```

It's a pretty typical implementation (ignoring the poor templatization and obvious memory leak).

I'm supposed to revise this algorithm so that it operates O(n) instead of O(n^2) using a priority queue. I'm not exactly sure how to implement this, but I'm guessing somewhere along the lines of this:

```
template <typename E> 
HuffTree<E>* buildHuff(HuffTree<E>** TreeArray, int count) {
    PriorityQueue<HuffTree<E>*, MIN_SORT> forest(count);
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        forest.enqueue(TreeArray[i], TreeArray[i]->weight());
    }

    HuffTree<E> *tree = NULL;
    HuffTree<E> *left, *right = NULL;
    while(forest.size() > 0) {
        left = forest.dequeue();
        if (tree) {
            right = tree;
        }
        else {
            right = forest.dequeue();
        }
        tree = new HuffTree<E>(left, right);
        delete left;
        delete right;
    }
    return tree;
}
```

But it doesn't work.

For the sake of brevity, I didn't include the referenced classes, but they're implementation is pretty straight forward. I would appreciate any advice to help steer me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation always selects the just-created tree as one of the children for the next tree. That's not correct. Consider the (ordered) frequencies:

```
1, 1, 1, 1, 3
```

The first two will be combined to produce a node with frequency 2, but the correct second node will not include that node.

---

I don't see how you can use a priority queue to make the solution O(n), since the priority queue requires O(log n) to remove the minimum element. (It can be built in O(n), but not the way you do it.)

If you're going to use an O(n log n) algorithm anyway, it's easier to just sort the frequencies in the first place. No further sorting needs to be done because the nodes which are produced are produced with monotonically non-decreasing frequencies, so there is no need for a priority queue to keep them sorted. What you need is to (incrementally) merge the sorted leaves and the (sorted as they are produced) non-leaves.